# Вывод строки атрибута placeholder для элемента textarea

Tags: html5, textarea, placeholder

Согласно спецификации HTML5 относительно атрибута `placeholder` элемента `textarea`

> User agents should present this hint to the user when the element’s
>   value is the empty string and the control is not focused (e.g., **by
>   displaying it inside a blank unfocused control**).

Однако пробуя такое объявление элемента `textarea`

```
<textarea name="story" rows="4" cols="60" id="form-story"
    maxlength="300" 
    placeholder="No more than 300 characters long.">
</textarea>
```

совместно с другими элементами в форме, текст атрибута `placeholder` не выводится в поле `textarea` по крайней мере ни  в  MS Edge, ни в Chrome.

Это результат того, что данный элемент объявлен неправильно, или существуют другие причины?

Comment: **"совместно с другими элементами в форме, текст атрибута placeholder не выводится"** у других элементов тоже нет placeholder'ов?  Вот [тут](https://jsfiddle.net/m8c9ngdy/) ваш пример работает, поэтому что еще подключено к странице (стили)? Я вижу другое описание атрибута placeholder [тут](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-textarea-element.html#attr-textarea-placeholder). Кроме того, у textarea нет атрибута [value](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-textarea-element).

Comment: @Mr.Brightside Это я по ошибке свойство интерфейса вставил. Но если его убрать, ничего не меняется. Другие элементы не имеют placeholder. Это просто поля ввода с типом tel, email.

Comment: @Mr.Brightside элемент <style> в заголовке присутствует. Единственное, что он определяет, это убирает у элементов ul изображения маркеров.

Answer (score 1):

У вас внутри `textarea` есть символ переноса строки, поэтому браузер не считает его пустым. Если убрать всё, что стоит между открывающим и закрывающим тегами, `placeholder` появится:

```html
<textarea name="story"
          rows="4"
          cols="60"
          id="form-story"
          maxlength="300" 
          placeholder="No more than 300 characters long."
></textarea>
```